# Dynamically removing angular.module()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to remove angular.module('SomeModule') dynamically?

This because I need to load and unload modules from a page in a tab-container.

This is based on Scott Moss' concept of where every single component is seen as a separate app on Frontendmasters.com.

I can get the module object by

```
angular.module(name)
```

Which returns an object respectively, but there I miss a clear way of clearing the references to this object. Has anyone solved something like this yet?

Template: http://plnkr.co/edit/8hK3lYjE7f06XtdHgNwL?p=preview

Comment: Are you talking about unregistering a module? Why would you want that?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yes this is what I mean. This because I am following a paradigm where components are seen as seperate applications. When a user navigates away or removes a view (component) I need to unload it from the DOM. But the user has the ability to add it again. But adding it gives me the error in question where the module is already registered
It's a silly thing, but with an app of potentially 200+ components. I was wondering if I can manage memory better by controlling the registry

Comment: I think you're confusing routing and dependency injection (with modules). You shouldn't remove modules from angular as it is used for dependency injection and the load ordering. Unloading DOM elements is done with controller and routes.

Comment: It sounds confusing I suppose since it's a new paradigm, really. They are self contained components and are not required in by any dependency injection by any other component. It is core of a ravioli design pattern (anti spaghetti as john papa would put it). Each component is it's own app, with it's own controller and services. It's a design pattern if anything. So the question is really if there is a way to remove a reference in the angular namespace. If there is not. then there is not. That is what I am here to find out :)

Comment: I think that once a module is made available inside angular, it can't be unregistered (at least without an undocumented hack). You can still remove every use of it through your app logic and that will keep the memory usage as low as possible.

Comment: I fear the same. It would be an undocumented hack most likely. I'll keep at it and post the answer if I find any if it's not too grotesque of course x)

Comment: To maximize the chances that someone help you or that the question serves a future reader, you should add more details to your question and describe the design pattern and how you want to implement it in your app. With that said, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be trying to optimize for something that doesn't exist.

First, there does not appear to be any documented way to remove modules. The reasons seem to be [covered in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module). In there you will find this statement (emphasis mine):

> The modules can be loaded in any order (or even in parallel) because **modules delay execution**.

In that sentence it doesn't specify for how long the delay is but later we get this snippet (again, emphasis mine):

> Because **modules do nothing at load time** they can be loaded into the VM in any order and thus script loaders can take advantage of this property and parallelize the loading process.

Put together, it sounds as if even with multiple of multiple modules, you won't notice a load on your site because the module will only be loaded when it is needed therefore removing modules is not a process that should ever need to be done.

Comment: Loading a component in a tab container and if you navigate away to load another component doesnt not remove the first component. This is fact. So it does not do this clean up in the DOM for you. I happen to have a very busy tab container due to a complex UI design. Meaning I need to lazy load and lazy offload content on tab container and have the ability to any other page and having that previous content be offloaded. I found a solution by dropping the "seperate apps" the pattern mentioned above and just $destroying directives. Thanks for the advice though :)

Comment: That sounds more like an issue with your tab component than with Angular. Controllers should be destroyed when no longer in use so unless your tab component continues to "use" each controller then that shouldn't be an issue. Though building in your own destroy process is always a good idea regardless.